# Disable admob ad unit serving ads for some time

Tags: android, admob

I try to find admob ad unit disable for some time period and find this help page
[Admob ad unit help](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3125713?hl=en)
But I couldn't find relevant information. 
Is anyone can help. How to disable ad unit for some time and then again restore in Google play published application.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can set "eCPM floor" in Ad Unit settings to a very high value like $1000000. This should disable this ad unit. You can do this globally or for specific countries.

Comment: This may have worked in 2018, but in 2021, Google caps the maximum value you can enter at $1000 which isn't enough to disable the ad unit

Comment: Can't you just create a house ad with 100% impression target? So, it won't serve any ads and you will earn 0?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should implement this in a back-end server so you can remotely enable/disable ads in your code. However, you can go to your admob console, "Blocking Controls" and block all categories to ensure no ads is served, and unblock when you want to show the ads. Not sure if it's against the policies though.

Comment: It is not possible to block all categories. Admob console just does not allow it. While blocking some categories, others magically start to become "too big to block". Really weird behavior.

Comment: @humbaba Really? I never tested it actually. It makes sense though